# How can I best find all the monsters with a given ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, gm-preparation

I frequently want to compile a list of monsters with a specific Special Ability, but doing so currently involves numerous Pfsrd searches and sorting through massive piles of noise, followed by fine-tuning for probable things that a SRD search would miss.  How can I do this more time-efficiently?

Comment: do you have an example of a Specific Ability you could want to search for?

Comment: For questions like *What are the most dangerous CR 3 monsters that have the special ability improved grab?*, I've heard [this site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is pretty good.  `;-)`

Comment: Maybe you could add to your question "using a pre-existing tool"? Because otherwise, the most efficient way to do so would undoubtedly be to create a tool to do exactly this. (Notwithstanding the expenditure of time to do so.)

Comment: @royalmurder It doesn't need to be a preexisting tool, but I'm more than 90% sure 'make one yourself' is going to be a heck of a lot less efficient than 'use this preexisting resource in this way', unless there's a real easy way to make a tool to do this, in which case, it'd be a great answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site [www.archivesofnethys.com](http://www.archivesofnethys.com) has a well working search option.
By giving the name of the special ability, for example earth glide, and checking the monsters box you should get an output of all monster descriptions including earth glide.

If a spell with the same name exists it will come up with monsters with that spell listed, too. As do those whose description includes your search term. 
But I use it on a regular basis to look for monsters with certain abilities.

Comment: Well, this does look really really good, but I worry about potential copyright issues here-- is that something I should be concerned about when using this resource for personal research?

Comment: As far as I know this site is allowed to use all material it is using so there should not be copyright issues. See [here](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/Licenses.aspx)